# Get prediction and distance with Scikit KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

According to the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html), Scikit's KNeighborsClassifier offers these two methods to get predictions:

1. **predict(X)** : Returns class labels.
2. **kneighbors(X)** : Returns distances and indices of the nearest points in the training data.

I'm in need of a mix of both: Getting the class label and the distance of that prediction. I'd like to avoid having to lookup the training data when using the kneighbors method (which returns only the index). Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

After you get the indices from **kneighbors(X)**, you can directly lookup the class label for each of those indices as such:

```
class_label = clf.classes_[clf._y[index]]
```